# Use fileinfo in stream

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

This is my code am trying to make a stream from the url and and i want to cut file into 6 pieces and download , because of that i want to connect the stream to file info but am getting some errors. thanks

```
FileInfo fs;
DateTime startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://tegos.ru/new/mp3_full/David_Guetta_feat_Ne-Yo_and_Akon_-_Play_Hard.mp3");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
using (Stream fileStream = fs new FileInfo("")))
```

error 'System.IO.FileInfo' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: "Some errors" - there's a much better chance someone will help you if you include the actual errors.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis in this line   using (Stream fileStream = FileInfo fs = new FileInfo("c:\\largefile.mp2"); 'System.IO.FileInfo' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to copy the stream from your HTTP response to a file:

```
using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite("pah_to_file"))
{
    using (Stream input = http.Response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048]; // some buffer
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

If it's not the case, do rephrase your question.

Comment: what you mean by this stream? i want to get stream from web url

Comment: @user2256550 This comment just doesn't help at all. Have you tested it? If it doesn't work, how does it fail (exception? doesn't compile?...?)?

Comment: @user2256550 Add precisions to your question cause it's not clear right now. You want to write data from a HTTP response to a file, don't you?

Comment: i did 
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://tegos.ru/new/mp3_full/David_Guetta_feat_Ne-Yo_and_Akon_-_Play_Hard.mp3");
             WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
             using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()) 
             //using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(@"c:\laragefile.mp3"))
             using (var fileStreams = new FileStream(@"c:\laragefile.mp3", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))

             {
                 string fils = fileStreams.ToString();

Comment: You know  am doing this to  make a program that  catch files from web and download, download means cut the files into many parts and download

Comment: How can i use the fileinfo ?

Comment: @user2256550 Why do you want to use `FileInfo` in the first place? Doesn't the provided code help to to what you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I told you , i want to get stream from a url and i want to use that stream to file info then i can cut the file into many peaces and download

Comment: @user2256550 This just doesn't make sense. Have you read the doc for `FileInfo`? There is no need for this class *at all* to download a file and save it into multiple parts. Have you even tried to understand the code I provided?

Comment: Huh,no. 1st i give url to download , the program cut the file in to 6 peaces and start downloading each files after the download the  downloaded peaces join. this what i mean